# Vue.js: Access data of array in another component

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, getusermedia, vue-props

I have a component where screenshots can be taken of the video. They are stored in an array and are displayed within the component under the video in a canvas.

What I want to achieve, however, is to access this array of screenshots in a different component (Gallery.vue) and to display all screenshots there. So, as soon as the screenshot button is clicked, the corresponding screenshot should be displayed in the other component.

This is how my Stream.vue component looks like which contains the video and the screenshot button (this components runs nice):

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div>
            <video ref="video" id="video" width="1024" height="576" autoplay></video>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 7px" id="snap" v-on:click="capture()">
                <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <canvas ref="canvas" id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="c in captures" :key="c.id">
                <img v-bind:src="c" height="50" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "camera",
    data() {
        return {
            video: {},
            canvas: {},
            captures: [],
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.initVideo();
    },
    methods: {
        initVideo() {
            this.video = this.$refs.video;
            if (
                "mediaDevices" in navigator &&
                "getUserMedia" in navigator.mediaDevices
            ) {
                navigator.mediaDevices
                    .getUserMedia({video: true})
                    .then((stream) => {
                        const videoPlayer = document.querySelector("video");
                        videoPlayer.srcObject = stream;
                        videoPlayer.play();
                    });
            } else {
                alert("Livestream currently unavailable.");
            }
        },
        capture() {
            this.canvas = this.$refs.canvas;
            // this.canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
            // this.canvas = document.getElementById("galleryCanvas");
            var context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
            this.captures.push(this.canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

The Gallery component where the screenshots should actually be accessed and displayed looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="gallery" id="mainDiv">
        <canvas ref="canvas" class="galleryCanvas" id="galleryCanvas" width="640" height="480" v-bind:captures="capture"></canvas>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="screenshot in captures" :key="screenshot.id">
                <img v-bind:src="screenshot" height="50" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- <div class="canvas" id="galleryCanvas"></div> -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "gallery",

    props: {
        captures: Array,
    },
};
</script>
```

So far I have tried multiple things. I tried accessing the canvas of the Gallery component via

```
this.canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
```

or by its ID via

```
this.canvas = document.getElementById("galleryCanvas");
```

but all of this would not work. It is just displaying a single screenshot in that component and as soon as I click the screenshot button it overwrites the screenshot instead of displaying the new screenshot next to the old one.

This might sound like a rather easy problem, but I am really struggling with it.
I really would appreciate any help.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean because your code works. I've simulated the same having each code within its component, here: https://jsfiddle.net/luismartin/6L17xt4e/
Anyways I've also tried creating a simple project with webpack and having separate files for each component. It still works: the array of video captures is displayed on the list.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That's strange. The props of the captures array in my other component (Gallery.vue) always states that it is undefined... In my stream component it works. I am wondering what I am doing different than you are?